Print to PDF in wine prints blank PDF
I have a problem I tried to resolve using virtually all help pages I could find, but hopefully you can help me - for now I have to resort to using actual Windows...
I want to use Chessbase Reader 2017 in WINE to print chess PGN files for training, but neither can I print actual pages nor PDF via cups-pdf. When I try the latter, it prints blank pages. I tried all sorts of things, modifying the printer to use the correct ppd via localhost:631, try to print to file, reinstall it all, install some OS print-to-pdf programs in WINE - nothing worked.
I'm at a dead end it feels. It seemingly should not be a big deal to print to a PDF in WINE, but it doesn't work after hours of trying.
Hope you all have some clues in this direction. Thanks!

First not everything works with Wine. Have you checked their site to see if it is supported? I do not see any version of Ubuntu mentioned in your question, yes it is necessary. Lastly that is very very very old software.

A pgn file is just a text file. You can use the default text editor in Ubuntu to print it.
Alternatively, VS Code (natively available on Ubuntu) has many extensions for interactively viewing pgn files, and you can use it for printing too.

Can someone explain the downvote?
